# Filter individual tables on one page Data Studio

Tags: google-sheets, filter, dashboard, looker-studio

I have 3 tables on one sheet. Now, I'd like to display data in every table for one value of a specific parameter. Lets say, I have price information about six types of fruit. Prices are for 3 countries (UK, US and DE).

My dataset looks like:

| DATE | COUNTRY | FRUIT TYPE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-20 | DE | Apple | 2.13 |
| 1-1-20 | UK | Apple | 1.53 |
| 1-1-20 | US | Apple | 2.48 |
| 1-1-20 | DE | Banana | 3.60 |
| 1-1-20 | UK | Banana | 5.82 |
| 1-1-20 | US | Banana | 2.83 |
| 2-1-20 | DE | Apple | 2.24 |
| 2-1-20 | UK | Apple | 1.35 |
| 2-1-20 | US | Apple | 2.49 |
| 2-1-20 | DE | Banana | 2.98 |
| 2-1-20 | UK | Banana | 5.32 |
| 2-1-20 | US | Banana | 2.23 |

I'd like to display 3 tables in Data Studio:

BANANA

| DATE | COUNTRY | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-20 | DE | 3.60 |
| 2-1-20 | DE | 2.98 |

APPLE

| DATE | COUNTRY | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-20 | DE | 2.13 |
| 2-1-20 | DE | 2.24 |

etc.

Country is done based on page filter (whole page could be changed by the user by use of the filter). However, if I add the "type fruit" as filter parameter for a specific table (Select the table -> "Data" > "Filter" > "Table Filter"), all tables change to the value of the filter I applied to one of the tables. So, if I select "apple" as fruit type in one table, the other tables do also display the values for apple.

How can I add a unique filter to every table on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can group a filter control and a table. Then the filter control will filter only the table(s) in the same group.